# MySQL SELECT only values with one occurence and the uniquesness depending on multiple columns

Tags: sql, mysql

I have a table with columns:

KEY1, KEY2, KEY3, KEY6, PLT_ID

There are rows where different KEY6 values have other (KEY1, KEY2, KEY3, PLT_ID) same, like:

| KEY1 | KEY2 | KEY3 | KEY6 | PLT_ID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | X | 1 |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | Y | 1 |

I need to filter only rows where there is only one occurrence of a combination of KEY1, KEY2, KEY3, PLT_ID for KEY6:

1,1,1,A,1 (where there is no other 1,1,1,*,1 in the table)

So when dataset will be:

| KEY1 | KEY2 | KEY3 | KEY6 | PLT_ID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | A | 1 |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | B | 1 |
| 1 | 1 | 0 | C | 1 |
| 1 | 1 | 0 | D | 0 |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | E | 0 |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | F | 0 |

I want my result have only:

| KEY1 | KEY2 | KEY3 | KEY6 | PLT_ID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 0 | C | 1 |
| 1 | 1 | 0 | D | 0 |

because of unique combination of (KEY1, KEY2, KEY3, PLT_ID).

Tried :

```
SELECT KEY1, KEY2, KEY3, KEY6, PLT_ID FROM RAWDATA WHERE KEY6 = 'Outbound' GROUP BY KEY1, KEY2, KEY3, KEY6, PLT_ID HAVING (COUNT(KEY1) = 1 AND COUNT(KEY2)  = 1 AND COUNT(KEY6)  = 1 AND COUNT(PLT_ID)  = 1);
```

but it does not work.

Comment: your first sample has the same key1 key2 key3 and plt_id, but in your text say you have diffenret of them , so ot is very unclear what you try to achieve add more samples and wanted result

Comment: Please format your data (both sample data and expected result) as tables with column headers so it is easy to read. Also update your question with the SQL you have managed to write

Comment: Sorry to be picky but that’s formatted as code not tables and you haven’t included the column headers

Comment: @nbk: Yes, updated.

Comment: @NickW: Yes, updated.

Answer (score 1):

The subquery will find the values you are looking for, which are only occuring once.

```
SELECT *
FROM mytable
WHERE (KeY1,Key2,Key3, PLT_ID) IN (SELECT KeY1,Key2,Key3, PLT_ID 
                                   FROM mytable
                                   GROUP BY KeY1,Key2,Key3, PLT_ID
                                   HAVING count(*)=1)
```

see: [DBFIDDLE](https://dbfiddle.uk/-6gfNJeh)

Answer (score 1):

You can Group bythe four columns and check that a unique number of the columns exist only once.

The unuque sum can be achieved ,y summing up the coumns but giving every columns a unique prime number

```
SELECT 
`KEY1`, `KEY2`, `KEY3`, MIN(`KEY6`) as KEY6, `PLT_ID`  
FROM tab
GROUP BY `KEY1`, `KEY2`, `KEY3`, `PLT_ID`
HAVING COUNT(`KEY1` + 3*   `KEY2` + 5 *  `KEY3`+ 7 * `PLT_ID`) = 1
```

| KEY1 | KEY2 | KEY3 | KEY6 | PLT_ID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 0 | C | 1 |
| 1 | 1 | 0 | D | 0 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/_S4MuMSf)

Answer (score 0):

Only group by the combination of keys you want to be unique, then you can just check for `COUNT(*) = 1` to find the rows that are the only instance of that combination.

The resulting SQL can look like this:

```sql
-- Definition
CREATE TABLE example (
  key1 int,
  key2 int,
  key3 int,
  key6 varchar(255),
  plt_id int
);

INSERT INTO example VALUES
(1,1,1,'A',1),
(1,1,1,'B',1),
(1,1,0,'C',1),
(1,1,0,'D',0),
(1,1,1,'E',0),
(1,1,1,'F',0);

-- Query
SELECT * FROM example
GROUP BY key1, key2, key3, plt_id
HAVING COUNT(*) = 1;
```

Example: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f4798a/4

Comment: Expression #4 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'fiddle.mytable.KEY6' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by
, see: [DBFIDDLE](https://dbfiddle.uk/Cm8-LfXT)